# CSS last-of-type Selector

Tags: html, css

I've recently been looking back into web design and learning new things with it. I am now using the `last-of-type` selector, and I'm trying to do so for a navigation bar, but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to.

HTML:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="inset-inner">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Now, I want to select the `last of type li` for this, so here is my CSS:

```
.main-nav ul li:last-of-type {
    color: green;
}
```

I do have a color set for the `a` element for this, so I have tried adding `!important`, but it doesn't help at all. The only way I can get it to work is if I make it like this:

HTML:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="inset-inner">
        <ul>
            <!--<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>-->
            <li><a href="">Home</a>
                <a href="">Contact</a>
                <a href="">About Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
/*
.main-nav ul li:last-of-type {
    color: green !important;
}
*/

.main-nav ul li a:last-of-type {
    color: green;
}
```

Now, how could I fix this for when I have a `li` element for each `a` element, and what is causing this anyways?

Comment: try adding `a` after last of type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `last-of-type` on the `<li>`, then add an `a` at the end:

```
.main-nav ul li:last-of-type a{
    color: green;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nK5yU/)**

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand your question correctly, you'd like for the last link to be green, using the `last-of-type` selector:

http://jsfiddle.net/YWfx2/

All you need to do is put the selector on the li and add the a tag after it!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="inset-inner">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS :**

```
.main-nav ul li:last-of-type a{
    color: green;
}
```